# Password-protecting encrypted web.config sections using aspnet_regiis

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, web-applications, aspnet-regiis.exe

We all know that encrypting and decrypting web.config sections can be easily accomplished using the aspnet_regiis tool... anybody with the right access to the server can do it. Is there a way to specify a password with the -pe or -pef option to further protect sensitive information?

Comment: um.. I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: Somebody with sufficient privileges _should_ be able to decrypt it...

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. This is because the application is supposed to know how to decrypt the sections.

What you can do is add another level of encryption (with password) within the application code.
This ensure you need to have access to the server AND to the source code to view the encrypted information.

hope this helps